# Transcoding rtsp over http

Tags: node.js, express, video, ffmpeg, stream

Before I explain my problem : Sorry for bad English and if you want you can help me on my spelling too.

I have a low cost IP camera who give only a RTSP link : 
192.168.x.x/onvif2
It doesn't need authentication to see video... my router doesn't have open ports^^

I want to trancode rtsp ( because  of html can't play it) with FFMPEG to send it on a server node.js ( express ) and in index.html play stream in video tag :

Server.js :

```
<script>
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    server.listen(8080);
    console.log("server run at 127.0.0.1:8080");

    io.on('connection',function(socket){
        socket.emit('hello','hello user');
    });
</script>
```

and index.html :

```
<html>
    <video style="background-color: black;" width="480" height="270" autoplay>
    <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"> 
    </video>

    <script>
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('hello',function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    </script>

</html>

ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.x.x/onvif2 -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -acodec aac -strict experimental -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 96k -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -b:v 500k -f flv http://127.0.0.1:xx/vid2.mp4
```

The camera starts but I can't find vid2.mp4

How can I replace ffserver with a node server (http? udp?...)

Answer (score 0):

mp4 files are not valid until the footer is written at the the stream. Use a streamable format like webm